# loop over column with lambda and calculate with values from other column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

hi I have the following Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [0.02,0.12,-0.1,0-0.07,0.01]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['new'] = ''
df['new'].iloc[0] = 100

df
```

I tried to calculate (beginning in row 1) in column 'new' the previous value divided by the value of 'col1'+ 1.

For example in row one, column new: 100/(0.12+1) = 89,285

For example in row two, column new: 89,285/(-0.10+1) = 99,206
and so on

I already tried to use a lambda function - without success. Thanks for help

Comment: Where does the 100 come from?

Comment: i like to index the data beginning with 100 - so I set 100. it is ok to ignore the first value (0.02) in my example. Thank you for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df['new'].iloc[0] = 100

for i in range(1,df.shape[0]):
    prev = df['new'].iloc[i-1]
    df['new'].iloc[i] = prev/(df['col1'].iloc[i]+1)
```

Output:

```
col1        new
-------------------
0   0.02    100
1   0.12    89.2857
2   -0.10   99.2063
3   -0.07   106.673
4   0.01    105.617
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [**numba**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#using-numba) is way how working with loops here if performance is important:

```
from numba import jit

d = {'col1': [0.02,0.12,-0.1,0-0.07,0.01]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.loc[0, 'new'] = 100

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a, b):
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        a[i] = a[i-1] / (b[i] +1)
    return a

df['new'] = f(df['new'].to_numpy(), df['col1'].to_numpy())
print (df)
   col1         new
0  0.02  100.000000
1  0.12   89.285714
2 -0.10   99.206349
3 -0.07  106.673494
4  0.01  105.617321
```

**Performance** for 5000 rows:

```
d = {'col1': [0.02,0.12,-0.1,0-0.07,0.01]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [168]: %timeit df['new'] = f(df['new'].to_numpy(), df['col1'].to_numpy())
277 µs ± 11.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [169]: %%timeit
     ...: for i in range(1,df.shape[0]):
     ...:     prev = df['new'].iloc[i-1]
     ...:     df['new'].iloc[i] = prev/(df['col1'].iloc[i]+1)
     ...:     
1.31 s ± 20.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [170]: %%timeit
     ...: for i_row, row in df.iloc[1:, ].iterrows():
     ...:     df.loc[i_row, 'new'] = df.loc[i_row - 1, 'new'] / (row['col1'] + 1)
     ...:     
2.08 s ± 93.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @Alex - Super, what is size of DataFrame? `print (len(df))` ?

Comment: just 80 rows, but there is a loop with 100 to 150 times

Comment: @Alex - I was curious, because loop in question is for 5000 rows.

Comment: you are welcome, your work was not worthless! because maybe in the future i will add an loop with 25  (20k) :)

Comment: @Alex - Super, be free reaccepting answer if my answer should woring better like Himanshu solution ;)

Comment: Since this isn't SIMD vectorizeable, turning off division by zero checking `@jit(nopython=True,error_model="numpy")` isn't that important here. But nervertheless it should provide some speedup and the function doesn't throw an exception if a division by zero happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any vectorized solution. Here's a sheer loop:

```
df['new'] = 100
for i_row, row in df.iloc[1:, ].iterrows():
    df.loc[i_row, 'new'] = df.loc[i_row - 1, 'new'] / (row['col1'] + 1)
```

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately, pandas seems to have no mechanism for a recursive rolling calculation, that might've come in handy.

Comment: yop, exactly, `numba` is way for this calculations